# Как получить текст который отдает консольное приложение?

Tags: delphi

Есть exe файл, который запускается через консоль. Как из cmd результат вывести в memo?

Comment: Можно поподробнее

Answer (score 2):

Примерно вот так - указываем рабочую папку и экзешник (если надо, с аргументами), получаем на выходе строку которую он бы вывел в консоль:

```
function CaptureConsoleOutput(const aFolder, aString: WideString): string;
const
  CReadBuffer = 2400;
var
  saSecurity: TSecurityAttributes;
  hRead: THandle;
  hWrite: THandle;
  suiStartup: TStartupInfo;
  piProcess: TProcessInformation;
  pBuffer: array [0 .. CReadBuffer] of AnsiChar;
  dRead: DWord;
  dRunning: DWord;
begin
  Result := '';

  saSecurity.nLength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
  saSecurity.bInheritHandle := True;
  saSecurity.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;

  if CreatePipe(hRead, hWrite, @saSecurity, 0) then
  begin
    try
      FillChar(suiStartup, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), #0);
      suiStartup.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
      suiStartup.hStdInput := hRead;
      suiStartup.hStdOutput := hWrite;
      suiStartup.hStdError := hWrite;
      suiStartup.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
      suiStartup.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;

      if CreateProcessW(nil, PWideChar(aString), @saSecurity, @saSecurity, True,
        CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, IfThen(aFolder <> '', PWideChar(aFolder), nil),
        suiStartup, piProcess) then
      begin
        CloseHandle(hWrite);
        try
          repeat
            dRunning := WaitForSingleObject(piProcess.hProcess, 100);

            repeat
              dRead := 0;
              if ReadFile(hRead, pBuffer[0], CReadBuffer, dRead, nil) then
              begin
                pBuffer[dRead] := #0;
                //OemToAnsi(pBuffer, pBuffer);
                Result := Result + String(pBuffer);
              end;
            until (dRead < CReadBuffer);
          until (dRunning <> WAIT_TIMEOUT);
        finally
          CloseHandle(piProcess.hProcess);
          CloseHandle(piProcess.hThread);
        end;
      end else
        raise Exception.Create('Can not CreateProcess ' + QuotedStr(aString));
    finally
      CloseHandle(hRead);
    end;
  end else
    raise Exception.Create('Can not CreatePipe ' + QuotedStr(aString));
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте выполнить перенаправление данных.
Например, exefile.exe >out.txt

Дальше работаете с данными в файле.